# In this sentence, does 되는 function as an adjective? verb?

Tags: verb-endings, subject-particle, adjective-endings

> 한국어의 모든 자음은,  받침으로 사용할 수 있지만,  음절의 끝소리가 되는 자음은 ‘ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅇ’의
>   7가지입니다.

This question is about 되는.

Usually 는  is is a marker for subjects or adjectives.

I thought 되는 자음은 might be an adjective + Noun. 
But 되는 means "become" and we don't really use "become" as an adjective in English except for expressions like "a becoming dress" or "a becoming event" - which I don't think is the meaning used here.

Someone told me "이/가 되는" means "can become" here. 
 - But why must it have the 는 marker? 
 - And where does "can" come from here? 이/가 x는 is not "can x".

Basically. What is the 는 in 되는 referring to here? a Subject? Adjective? or What else?

Answer (score 2):

Saying that the -는 ending creates an adjective can be a bit confusing.  Technically, it creates a [participle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle), which is the form of the verb which *acts* like an adjective, that is, by modifying a following noun.

These are primarily used in Korean to create **relative clauses**, for example:

> **멀리 보는 사람**들이 성공할 수 있다
>   **People who see far** ahead can be successful

Here, the relative clause in English "who see far" comes after the noun it modifies "people", but in Korean, it's always the opposite:  the participle "보는" comes right before the noun "사람".

Looking at your sentence:

> 음절의 끝소리가 되는 자음

We can see that the main noun is 자음 (consonant), the participle is 되는 (that becomes), which has the subject 음절의 끝소리가 (the final sound of the syllable), which put together is:

> consonants that (can) become the final sound of the syllable.

Looking at the complete sentence, it says:

> 한국어의 모든 자음은, All of the consonants in Korean
>   받침으로 사용할 수 있지만, can be used in the bottom of the (written) syllable but 
>   음절의 끝소리가 되는 자음은 ‘ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅇ’의 7가지입니다 the consonants that can become the final (spoken) sound of the syllable are just 7 (ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅇ).

These relative clauses formed by participles are a very important part of the Korean grammar.  They are very flexible, so that the participle can be preceded by a subject (as in your example) or an object.  See the difference:

> 강아지가 먹는 고기 (meat that the dog eats)
>   고기를 먹는 강아지 (the dog that eats meat)

It's important to also know the past participle (ending in -ㄴ) and future participle (ending -ㄹ):

> 강아지가 먹은 고기 (the meat eaten by the dog)
>   가아지가 먹을 고기 (the meat the dog will eat).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the sentence `"음절의 끝소리가 되는 자음은 ‘ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅇ’의 7가지입니다."` as `"자음 which can be 음절의 끝소리 are 'ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅇ'의 7가지."` So `"자음"` is the subject in the sentence.

Comment: I was asking about 되는, not 자음은.는 in 되는 referring to here? a Subject? Adjective? or something else?